# Change sprite text dynamically on chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, sprite, extjs5

Is there any way to change sprite text dynamically on a chart?

This is not working:

```
this.lookupReference('chart').setText('Second Text');
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mij

Comment: you need to redraw the chart, because the chart text is inside a canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handler: function(){
            var chart=this.next();
            chart.setSprites({
                type: 'text',
                reference: 'sprites',
                text: 'Second text  ',
                font: '13px Helvetica bold',
                width: 100,
                height: 30,
                x: 50, // the sprite x position
                y: 17  // the sprite y position
            });
            chart.redraw();
        }
```

[here is your forked working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mji)

The chart is made by a canvas, you can't get a specific "piece of the chart" and modify it, so you simply need to redraw the chart with the new text.